# Conditionally applying class that changes on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, reactive-programming

I have a react component I am attempting to set an "active" class too. Here's my code I am using to test if the active class should be set.

```
  {sku.colors &&
  (<div className="swatches" styleName="swatches">
      <span className="color" styleName="color" data-name="color">
    {sku.colors.map((option, index) => {   
      return(
        <span className={this.state.selectedColor === option.name ? 'active': ''} styleName="swatch" onClick={this.onColorChange.bind(this, option.name)} style={{backgroundImage: 'url(' + swatchImg + ')' }} key={index}>{option.name}</span>
      )
    })}
    </span>
  </div>)                
}
```

I have the state.selectedColor defined as a prop

```
constructor(props) {
super(props);

this.state = { selectedColor: 'Black' };
}
```

And here's my onClick function:

```
onColorChange(currentColor){
//add sizes for this color
this.state.selectedColor = currentColor;
}
```

The problem is the  is only checking if selectedColor = option.name when the component is first loaded. The check does not happen again after the onClick function fires, so the active class is never updated.

I am thinking I may need to re-render that section after the onClick event. Does anyone have any opinions/advice for solving this issue?

EDIT: I can see the state.selectedColor is being updated correctly on the click event, but the active class check is not working.

I added:

```
console.log(this.state.selectedColor);
```

and it does update correctly on click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try thus:

```
onColorChange(currentColor){
//add sizes for this color
this.setState({selectedColor: currentColor});
}
```

Comment: Setting the state is working correctly, but the check on the selectedColor does not happen except for the first time. See my edit that includes the console.log.

Comment: I did try your code just to be sure, and I get the same results. the selectedColor is updated, but class does not respond.

Comment: Try to change your function event, like:  onClick={() => this.onColorChange(option.name)}

Comment: You're initial code worked for me. I had a syntax error and it worked perfectly after I solved it. The setState does in fact force a re-render, and that solved my problem.

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 2):

You should use `this.setState({ selectedColor: currentColor })` instead of `this.state.selectedColor = currentColor`. You should never try to update your state properties by assigning values to them directly. This is probably why a rerender is not being triggered as well.

This is also stated in the React Docs: [state](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#state)

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is correct, you do need a re-render after you modify `state.selectedColor`.

Using `this.setState({selectedColor: currentColor})` function will update your state and then immediately set off a re-render. This is a tool that React provides since this is such a common action (i.e. changing the state and then re-rendering).

One thing to keep in mind is that using `setState` inside of the `render` function can cause an infinite loop.

Comment: This seems to be correct, I'm not sure why the re-render isn't working for me.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! After fixing a syntax error, this worked perfectly for me.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you are doing everything right? It works here:

```js
const sku = {
  colors: [
    { id: 1, name: "Black" },
    { id: 2, name: "Red" },
    { id: 3, name: "White" },
  ],
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedColor: "Red"
  };
  
  onColorChange ( currentColor ) {
    this.setState( { selectedColor: currentColor } );
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {sku.colors && (
          <div className="swatches" styleName="swatches">
            <span className="color" styleName="color" data-name="color">
              {sku.colors.map((option, index) => (
                <span
                  className={
                    this.state.selectedColor === option.name ? "active" : ""
                  }
                  styleName="swatch"
                  onClick={this.onColorChange.bind(this, option.name)}
                  key={index}
                >
                  {option.name}
                </span>
              ))}
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Also, if you extract each `option` into its component you don't need to bind your function in your JXS directly. So, it won't be created in every render. If you use it like this or with an arrow function it will be created in every render. Also, if you look your console React warns you about using `styleName` attribute as `stylename`.

```js
const sku = {
  colors: [
    { id: 1, name: "Black" },
    { id: 2, name: "Red" },
    { id: 3, name: "White" },
  ],
};

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    selectedColor: "Red",
  };

  onColorChange = currentColor =>
    this.setState( { selectedColor: currentColor } );

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {sku.colors && (
          <div className="swatches" styleName="swatches">
            <span className="color" styleName="color" data-name="color">
              {sku.colors.map( option => (
                <Option
                  key={option.id}
                  option={option}
                  selectedColor={this.state.selectedColor}
                  onColorChange={this.onColorChange}
                />
              ) )}
            </span>
          </div>
        )}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Option = ( props ) => {
  const { option, selectedColor, onColorChange } = props;
  const handleChange = () => onColorChange( option.name );

  return (
    <span
      className={
        selectedColor === option.name ? "active" : ""
      }
      styleName="swatch"
      onClick={handleChange}
    >
      {option.name}
    </span>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
.active {
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: My issue ended up being what the other commenters brought up. I was updating the state directly rather than using setState. Thank you for providing this working example. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome. Actually, I've provided this answer after seeing your comment on @Gaspar's answer. The one you said although changing the code that sets the state, getting the same result. Glad that you solved your problem.